# Json server run without db.json

Tags: json, json-server

Dear stackoverflow members,
I have public folder which is running in `json-server`.I would like know is the anyway to run `json-server --watch db.json`, without `db.json`. I got an error when I write only `json-server`, that I must provide `--watch` part.

Comment: That's how this program works. If you have an issue with that or desire different behavior then go to the Github site for it and open an issue

Comment: @JimDeville I have no any issue. I didn't find anywhere that  is it possible to do this if I will only configure json-server which can run over the public folder, without db.json. Anyway if I will even create free db.json file json-server will work. So my point was to find a way to run without db.json, only over the public folder

Comment: But what is the point of using a software that creates a rest api from a json file without an actual json file? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user7607595 what you mean is using another server, one wichi is not specialized in mocking api.